# MouseEnter and MouseLeave in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, label

My program in wpf is adding labels dynamically based on conditions. However I'm having some trouble setting the MouseEnter and MouseLeave settings for the labels. This is what I have right now.

```
Test1.MouseEnter += PresetLabelHover(ID);
Test1.MouseLeave += PresetLabelHoverEnd();
```

where PresetLabelHover will make the label with name PresetLabel visible, while PresetLabelHoverEnd will make the label with name PresetLabel invisible. ID is a number that the program uses, and it needs to pass to the PresetLabelHover for it to set the content of the PresetLabel. Test1 is the label that the program makes.

The error I'm getting is that

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to System.Windows.Input.MouseEventHandler'
```

This is my code for the PresetLabelHover and PresetLabelHoverEnd

```
private void PresetLabelHover(int number)
{
    PresetLabel.Content = number;
    PresetLabel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}

private void PresetLabelHoverEnd()
{
    PresetLabel.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}
```

Overall, this is what's supposed to happen.

Program inserts labels. When the mouse hover over the specific label, it'll make a different label visible with values the number I pass into it. Once the mouse leaves the label area, the other label will go invisible.

If someone can help me with this it'll be great. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

i think mouse enter and mouse leave are events handlers like click and stuff... you should be able to add those from your designer... just click on your label and check under "events" tab... then look for a mouse enter and mouse leave events... should look something like this

```
    private void Label1_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Content = number; 
        Label1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

Comment: I understand that, but the thing is that these labels are created when the program runs, so it's not visible in the XAML file at the beginning. The label that's getting shown when the mouse is over the dynamically created label's content depends on which label the mouse is over :\

Comment: oh... gotcha... well another approach you could try is creating your own custom label and just add the mouse enter and leave handlers inside the control

Comment: I figured out an alternative but that requires me to put in X extra functions based on how many extra labels my program creates :(

Comment: @User13888, based on your first comment, you can have one event handler that works for multiple labels. Create an event handler in code manually similar to the one Dark Templar coded above, and assign it to each of the labels as you create them.

Note that you should also make sure to remove the event handlers if you're destroying the labels, in order to avoid memory leaks.